# Certain console apps "automagically" open a new console

Tags: windows-7, command-line, console

Without installing anything new, certain console apps (eg `xxcopy`, `diskpart`) began to open a new console instead of displaying the output in the current console as usual:

- If I run `CMD`, a new console appears (ok so far)
- If I run most external commands (`NET USE, SCHTASKS`, etc) the output is shown in the *current* console (ok)
- If I run `DISKPART` or `XXCOPY`, a *new console* appears with the DISKPART prompt instead of displaying the output on the current console

My main problem is with XXCOPY64, a file copy program: I used to run a batch file that runs several XXCOPY commands sequentially, but now each command runs concurrently in its own console.

I tried to fix this problem:

- checking posible virus infections with DrWebCureIt and manually with SysInternals Autoruns
- checking the integrity of both .EXEs with MD5
- fixing posible corrupt registry **RUN** entries with [FixExec](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/fixexec)
- disabling my antivirus, renaming the XXCOPY64 exe for any possible registry specific configuration and even modified the XXCOPY exe with an binary editor
- running the programs from a different console than `CMD.EXE`, eg [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/)

No luck so far, and running out of ideas :)

My OS is Windows 7 Professional 64b

Comment: What is the output of `where diskpart` and `where xxcopy64`?

Comment: @DavidPostill: 
`where diskpart` > `C:\Windows\System32\diskpart.exe`  
`where xxcopy64` > `E:\Utiles\xxcopy64.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `DISKPART` and `XXCOPY`, this appears to be related to UAC. Running them from a unprivileged console causes a UAC prompt to show and then launches the commands in a new, privileged console. Initiating these commands from a privileged console ("Run as Administrator...") causes them to run within the same console and without the UAC prompt.

Comment: perfect answer! That was the problem, I ran the backup script as administrator and works fine this time. I still don't know what changed because I never had to "run as administrator"  the script before. I didn't realize the problem was related to UAC because I have the UAC warning disabled